# Googleway not considering traffic for travel time (directions search)

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api, googleway

Using the `google_directions` function from `googleway` package, it does not display the travel time according to google maps browser search.

It seems that it is not taking into account the traffic information.

Example on a busy street in New York.

```
a <- google_directions(origin = c(40.862804, -73.934743),
              destination = "212 5th Ave, New York, NY 10010, USA",
              mode = "driving",
              units = "metric",
              simplify = TRUE,
              key = MY_API)
```

The response at the current time:

```
b <- direction_steps(a)
total_time <- sum(b$duration$value)/60  # minutes
total_time                              # minutes
#[1] 26.1166
```

However, google maps browser displays 35 minutes for the same search time. I checked the routes and it is the same.

[image]

Same thing happens using `mapsapi` package:

```
c <- mp_directions(origin = c(-73.934743,40.862804),
               destination = "212 5th Ave, New York, NY 10010, USA",
                 mode = "driving",
                 key = MY_API)
total_time1 <- sum(mp_get_segments(c)$duration_s)/60 # minutes
total_time1                                          # minutes
# [1] 26.11667
```

Does anyone know how to incorporate traffic info into these functions? Or should I conclude google does not provide this level of information?

Comment: Good question. I can't immediately see why they would be different [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `googleway` documentation for `google_directions` covers this. To get real-time data, you need the following:

- a `departure_time`, either current using `"now"` or a specified future time using a `POSIXct` datetime.
- `traffic_model`: Whether Google's guess should be `best_guess`, `optimistic`, or `pessimistic`.

You asked for a historical travel time with your code, while Google Maps use the real-time travel time (likely the `best_guess` estimate).

[The Google documentation states](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro):

> `best_guess` (default) indicates that the returned `duration_in_traffic` should be the best estimate of travel time given what is known about both historical traffic conditions and live traffic. Live traffic becomes more important the closer the `departure_time` is to now.

Try this instead:

```
a <- google_directions(
    origin = c(40.862804, -73.934743),
    destination = "212 5th Ave, New York, NY 10010, USA",
    mode = "driving",
    units = "metric",
    simplify = TRUE,
    key = MY_API,
    departure_time = "now",
    traffic_model = "best_guess")

# Travel time in seconds
travel_time <- a$routes$legs[[1]]$duration_in_traffic$value
```

Comment: Thank you Christian! That's correct! For some reason (perhaps at that time the function `duration_in_traffic` wasn't available or I didn't pay enough attention). Now its working and the results are the same as found on google maps browser.